# Fractional number systems

Tags: reference-request, recreational-mathematics

Given a natural number $n>1$. It is well-known that any real number $r$ can be written as 
$$\sum_{i=-\infty}^{\infty}a_in^i$$ such that $a_i\in \left\{0,1,\dots n-1\right\}=C$.

For the decimal system $n=10$ and in the binary system $n=2$.

I was wondering whether a similar statement holds when $n\in \mathbb{Q}$ (or even $\mathbb{R}$). For example if $n=\frac{3}{2}$, how many coefficients do we need to allow for this to work? If $C=\mathbb{Z}$ it is still possible. But what is the smallest coefficient set we need to allow?

I'm fairly certain someone has thought about this and something is known. I'd be very happy with a reference on this subject.

Comment: https://brilliant.org/wiki/fractional-number-base/ , https://www.quora.com/Can-we-have-a-fractional-base-number-system

Comment: @EthanBolker: Yup, that's exactly what I suspected, couldn't  find a good reference though. I always found someone asking how to convert an fraction to some (integral) number system. After some thinking I also concluded that $C$ defined as the the natural numbers less than $n$ is the smallest coefficient set that still allows you to write any number in base $n$. Thus the additional question on the smallest coefficient set is also solved. Thanks for the references, if you post that as an answer I'll accept and close this :)

Comment: Next you can try interesting **complex** numbers.  For example base $1+i$ with digits $\{0,1\}$.

Comment: It's funny that working in base $\phi$ (the golden ratio), we have that $100=11$. This follows from the relation $\phi^2=\phi+1$. It's nothing new that a number doesn't have a unique representation (e.g. $0,999\dots=1,00\dots)$, but it is new that this happens for finite representations.

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged so I can't just post them, and I don't want to take the time to write some text to go with the links. You can answer your own question (accepted practice here) so it doesn't stay on the unanswered queue. Let me know when  you do and I'll upvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments, this question has a positive answer:

Let $b\in\mathbb{R}$ and assume $b>1$. Then any real number $r$ can be written as 
$$\sum_{i=-\infty}^{\infty}a_ib^i$$ where $a_i\in \left\{0,1,\dots ,n\right\}$ where $n$ is the largest natural number smaller than $n$. One can verify that leaving out a coefficient gives rise to certain real numbers that can no longer be expressed in this way.

References can be found in Ethan Bolker's comment and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-integer_representation).